# updating the listview using handler and notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, json, listview

i'm trying to update the listview for every sec,so i used the handler and thread to update

i used the `notifyDataSetChanged();` to reload the `listview` without refreshing the activity.

but my listview is not updating.

how can i update my listview repeatedly  without refresh the activity

```
  private class MessageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
         private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String output = "";
            for (String url : urls) {

                 try{
                 HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                 ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                output = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

                 }catch(Exception e){
                     Log.i("Animation", "Thread  exception " + e);
                 }
                 }
            return output;
        }



        protected void onPostExecute(String output) {




    try {


        JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject(output);
        JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray(jObject.getString("response"));   
        ArrayList<String> tExp=new ArrayList<String>();
        //HashMap<String,ArrayList> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList>();

     for (int i = 0; i<menuObject.length(); i++)
     {

         tExp.add(menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("fk_username_c").toString()+" "+menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("message_c").toString());




     }
     adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChatActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
     adapter.addAll(tExp);

     final Handler handler = new Handler();
     handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
             adapter.setNotifyOnChange(isChangingConfigurations());
             handler.postDelayed( this,  1000 );
         }
     },  1000 );

     listview.setAdapter(adapter);  

     } catch (JSONException e) {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
     }

     //intent.putExtra(extras);



 }
}
```

Comment: my listview is not updating

Comment: is this code written in asynctsk?

Comment: @user2582340 where are you changing the underlying data that populates listview. where are you populating data in your list?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia yes i written it using asynctask

Answer (score 0):

You are running updation of list in a separate thread which leads the execution of refreshing the list before even the list is modified or updated actually.

if you debeg your code then you can see that it is working fine because the thread got enough time to get executed.